# Changing string to NULL after the first iteration of cycle. Memory allocation

Tags: c, string, visual-c++, memory, memory-management

The program should get the string from the file and separate them finding string "delim" in it. I should use dynamic memory but to my sorry I can't use it perfectly. Whats the reason for changing "cpystr" from "SUCCESSZOMBIEAAAAAAAaaaAZOMBIEaaAZOMBIEdf" to NULL after the first iteration of the cycle?"SUCCESSZOMBIEAAAAAAAaaaAZOMBIEaaAZOMBIEdf" where "ZOMBIE" is "delim". Help me to fix that. Thx for the help in advance!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

char** split(const char *str, const char *delim)
{
    int cntr1, cntr2, cntr3, cntdelim=0;
    bool check;
    //counting "delim" in the str

    char **maspntr=NULL;
    char *cpystr=NULL;
    cpystr=_strdup(str); //reserve copy of the "cpy"
    strcpy(cpystr,str);
    for (cntr1=0;cntr1<(strlen(cpystr)+1);cntr1++) //THE PROBLEM WITH THIS CYCLE!
    {

    check=1;
    for (cntr2=0, cntr3=cntr1;cntr2<strlen(delim); cntr2++, cntr3++) //searching for "delim" 
        if (!(cpystr[cntr3]==delim[cntr2]))
            {

                check=0;
                break;
            }
        if (check) //if it's foound, it copies the first N characters as the first element of pointers' array 
        {

            maspntr=(char**)realloc(maspntr,(cntdelim+1)*sizeof(char*));
            maspntr[cntdelim]=(char*)calloc(cntr1, sizeof(char));
            cntdelim++;
            for (cntr3=0;cntr3<=(strlen(cpystr)-(cntr1+strlen(delim)-2));cntr3++)
            {
                cpystr[cntr3]=cpystr[cntr3+cntr1+strlen(delim)];
                cpystr=(char*)realloc(cpystr,(strlen(cpystr)+1-cntr1-strlen(delim))*sizeof(char)); //delete first N characters +"delim" by copying the characters from the end then modifying memory
            }

        }
         if(cpystr[cntr1]='\0') //if it is the end of string return
         {

             for (cntr1=0; cntr1<sizeof(maspntr); cntr1++)
         {
             printf(maspntr[cntr1],'\n');
         }
             free(cpystr);

             return(maspntr);
         }

    }   //Changing "cpystr" to NULL right here






}
int main()
{
    char singlech;
    int len=0;

    //copy string from the file to the variable
    FILE* foo;
errno_t err;
    err=fopen_s(&foo,"input.txt","r");
    if( err == 0 )
  {
      printf( "The file 'input.txt' was opened\n" );
  }
  else
  {
      printf( "The file 'input.txt' was not opened\n" );
  }
    while (!feof(foo))  //rather stupid way of getting memory
    {
        fscanf_s(foo, "%c", &singlech);
        len++;
    }
    char *str=NULL, *delim=NULL;

    str=(char*)calloc(len,sizeof(char));
    rewind(foo);
    fgets(str,len,foo);
    delim=(char*)calloc(sizeof("ZOMBIE")+1, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(delim,"ZOMBIE");
    split(str,delim);
    printf(str);
    free(str);
    free(delim);

    getchar();

}
```

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem from 90+ lines of code

Comment: Debugger? Why not try that

Comment: SSCCE http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Ed Heal , i've already tried and found the problem (read the discription plz). Added a comment to the problem cycle to make it clearer.

Comment: Why do you make rep lower and even do not try to help? If you can't help with the problem, help me to edit the question and make it better.

Comment: There are loads of errors here. No idea where to start.

Comment: @David Heffernan Oh! Start from the very beginning plz. I'm listening carefully)

Comment: Your use of sizeof is the biggest problem. All the calls in your code return the size of a pointer.

Comment: @David Heffernan and how can I allocate memory for an array of chars (str,cpystr,delim)? The second question is how can I do it for an array of pointers (maspntr)?

Comment: Use strlen to obtain length of a string.

Comment: @David Heffernan should i use 
str=(char*)malloc(len); instead of
str=(char*)calloc(len,sizeof(char)); ?

Comment: @David Heffernan and what about allocating memory for an array of pointers (maspntr)?

Comment: Those size of OK. Others no good. You need to throw away this code and learn C from scratch again. You are not yet anywhere near competent enough to write this program.

Comment: @David Heffernan To my sorry, i'm learning C for 2 months :) and it's one of my tasks for the university. I'm learning to allocate memory on practice.

Comment: You really need to back up and learn to walk before attempting to run. You will learn little and slowly the way you are going.

Answer (score 2):

I did not read all your code, but

```
cpystr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(cpystr))
```

allocates "size of pointer" bytes (perhaps 4 or 8), therefore the following `strcpy()`
writes beyond the allocated memory.

You probably mean

```
cpystr = malloc(strlen(str) + 1); // casting the return value of malloc not needed
```

But why not write simply

```
cpystr = strdup(str);
```

instead of `malloc() + strcpy()` ?

Comment: cause I didn't even know about strdup :)
I'll check whether the program works now.

Comment: it works, thx for the help. But the main problem still exists.

Comment: This is your main problem. You do this over and over.